# Adding social buttons indrop-up menu

Tags: html

How to add social buttons Drop-up menu using HTML. like LinkedIn, Gmail, Twitter, etc.

*Instead of link 1, link 2, link 3, I want to add social buttons in the menu. How can I do this?

Comment: can you be more specifique? (you have an image or something like that with what you like to it appear)

Comment: Thank you so much, ma'am. I have found a solution.